# How to use Flask, HTML, and JavaScript to show a separate website inside an HTML column?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm building a website using Flask. This website allows a user to select from numerous computation algorithms and applies the selected algorithm on data the user uploaded. This really isn't important for this question. What is important, is that during my sandboxing and learning Flask/HTML/JavaScript, I once accidentally tried to redirect my web page on button click to refresh the `index.html`. Instead, I put the code in an HTML column or something, and clicking the button accidentally populated that HTML column with another copy of my `index.html` within my main `index.html`!

Now, I fixed that problem a long time ago, but now I have a situation for which I would like to recreate that particular code.

I have a column in my web page that is updated to show results. On button click, I would like to refresh a web page displayed in this column, rather than refreshing the whole `index.html`.

How can I recreate this `web page in-a-column` construct I accidentally made previously?

Edit: I want to clarify that I want the webpage to load in the dimensions of the pre-defined column and span the entire column. For example, I am using a `<style>` which includes a defined `.right { width: 65%; }`, so I want the webpage to fit perfectly in that space.

Comment: Are you sure you wanted the (Adobe) `Flash` tag?

Comment: Thanks, i did in fact want flask!